# regular expression (vim) asterisk replace

Tags: regex

In this simple code:

```
char **s = NULL;
char **s1 = NULL;
```

I want to replace "**s" with "*s",

the result should be:

```
char *s = NULL;
char **s1 = NULL;
```

but if I try:

```
%s/\<\*\*s\>/\*s/g
```

replace failed.
If try this:

```
%s/\*\*s/\*s/g
```

the result is:

```
char *s = NULL;
char *s1 = NULL;
```

replace succeded, but also "**s1" is replaced

Why the first method FAIL?

Comment: Why does the first one have `\<` and `\>`?

Comment: for exactly matching http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Comment: By the way, here's a working one.  `%s/\**s\s/*s /`  Your second one matched both because you didn't specify what comes after the "s".
`

Comment: That's true, but i want to understand because the first will not work

Comment: The first doesn't work because you have less-than and greater-than signs... they don't appear anywhere in the input.

Comment: less-than and greater-than need to search the exaclty word to substitute, infact if I do: `%s/\<NULL\>/Pippo/g` the replace is right

Answer (score 2):

In vim regular expressions, `\<` means a word boundary. There's no word boundary between the space and the asterisk — neither one is part of a word — so `\<\*` doesn't match. You need this:

```
%s/\*\*s\>/\*s/g
```

which addresses that issue, while still retaining the word-boundary after `s` (so as not to match `*s1`). (`\<` and `\>` are frequently used in pairs to match a whole word, but they don't have to be. Either can be used without the other.)